# Managing Refresh Tokens for Scheduled Data Factory Copy Activity from API

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I need some help.

I am building a pipeline in Data Factory which copies data from an external API and I need some help managing the refresh tokens to make the pipeline automated. Is anyone able to help me with the following questions:

- How I can add a new version of a secret to Azure Key Vault based on the output of a pipeline activity. I know how to access the the refresh token value from a previous pipeline activity using dynamic content but not how to set the new value in the key store.
- If the above line is successful, is it possible to create a variable that accesses the latest version of a secret?
- Is it possible to automate deleting of previous key versions based on time (e.g. delete all from 2 days ago) or based on number (delete the keys so that only the 10 most recent remain).

You guys are awesome. Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your last 2 questions.

When you run a get secret command on key vault it will always return the latest version of the secret if you do not specify a version, you can store the output of this in your variable.

Key Vault does not currently support deleting specific versions of secrets, keys, or certificates.

Comment: Thanks Shane, those are both very useful.